# passing value from one activity to an other aondroid app crashed

Tags: android, android-studio

by passing from one activity app crashed .
can some one help me.
i have try multiple methods.
thanks in advance to all of you.

> ```
> package com.wing.test2.test2;
>
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.EditText;
>
>
> public class person extends AppCompatActivity {
>     Button submit_person;
>     EditText user_ida,name,gander,age;
>     //Intent  patient_data = new Intent(this, patient.class);
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
>         setContentView( R.layout.activity_person );
>
>
>
>         submit_person = (Button) findViewById( R.id.submit_person );
>         user_ida = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.userid );
>         name = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.name );
>         gander = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.gander );
>         age = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.age );
>
>         submit_person.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View arg0) {
>                    Log.v( "EditText", user_ida.getText().toString() );
>                     Log.v( "EditText", name.getText().toString() );
>                     Log.v( "EditText", gander.getText().toString() );
>                     Log.v( "EditText", age.getText().toString() );
>
>
>                     String user_id = user_ida.getText().toString();
>                     String user_name = name.getText().toString();
>                     String user_gander = gander.getText().toString();
>                     String user_a = age.getText().toString();
>
>                     Intent patient_data =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),patient.class);
>
>                     patient activity = new patient();
>                     activity.displayInfo(user_name,user_gander,user_id,user_a);
>                     startActivity(patient_data);
>
>                     /*patient_data.putExtra("id",user_id);
>                     patient_data.putExtra( "name", user_name );
>                     patient_data.putExtra( "gander", user_gander );
>                     patient_data.putExtra( "age", user_a );
>                     startActivity( patient_data );
>                     */
>                 }
>             } );
>
>     }
>
> }
> ```

==============================================

## other  activity

> package com.wing.test2.test2;
>
> ```
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.widget.EditText;
> import android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class patient  extends person {
>
>    //Intent patient_data = getIntent();
>    person patient_data = new person();
>
>     TextView textView2,textView,textView3,textView4;
>
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>     {
>         super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
>         setContentView(R.layout.patient);
>         Log.v( "EditText", patient_data.toString() );
> /*
>         String user_id = patient_data.getStringExtra("id");
>         String name = patient_data.getStringExtra("name");
>         String gander = patient_data.getStringExtra("gander");
>         String user_age = patient_data.getStringExtra("age");
>         textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
>         textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
>         textView3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
>         textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
>
>         textView2.setText(user_id);
>         textView.setText(name);
>         textView3.setText(gander);
>         textView4.setText(user_age);*/
>     }
>     public void displayInfo(String name, String gander, String user_ida, String age)
>     {
>         textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
>         textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
>         textView3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
>         textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
>
>         textView2.setText( (CharSequence) user_ida );
>         textView.setText( (CharSequence) name );
>         textView3.setText( (CharSequence) gander );
>         textView4.setText( (CharSequence) age );
>     }
> }
> ```

here is error log

```
02-10 02:35:08.651 19910-19910/com.wing.test2.test2 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-10 02:35:08.721 19910-19910/com.wing.test2.test2 V/EditText: 12
02-10 02:35:08.731 19910-19910/com.wing.test2.test2 V/EditText: 12
02-10 02:35:08.731 19910-19910/com.wing.test2.test2 V/EditText: 233
02-10 02:35:08.731 19910-19910/com.wing.test2.test2 V/EditText: Wer
02-10 02:35:08.741 19910-19910/com.wing.test2.test2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-10 02:35:08.751 19910-19910/com.wing.test2.test2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.wing.test2.test2, PID: 19910
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:68)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:190)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:172)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:512)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:184)
                                                                          at com.wing.test2.test2.patient.displayInfo(patient.java:39)
                                                                          at com.wing.test2.test2.person$1.onClick(person.java:47)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
02-10 02:35:26.458 19910-19910/com.wing.test2.test2 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19910 SIG: 9
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your error's stack trace.

Comment: why are u extending `person` instead of `activity`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this: in your first activity

```
Intent patient_data =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),patient.class);
patient_data.putExtra("id",user_id);
patient_data.putExtra( "name", user_name );
patient_data.putExtra( "gander", user_gander );
patient_data.putExtra( "age", user_a );
startActivity(patient_data);
```

Also remove:

```
patient activity = new patient();
activity.displayInfo(user_name,user_gander,user_id,user_a);
```

Now in second activity use:

```
    public class patient extends Activity {

   person patient_data = new person();

    TextView textView2,textView,textView3,textView4;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView(R.layout.patient);
        Log.v( "EditText", patient_data.toString() );

        Intent patient_data = getIntent();
        String user_id = patient_data.getStringExtra("id");
        String name = patient_data.getStringExtra("name");
        String gander = patient_data.getStringExtra("gander");
        String user_age = patient_data.getStringExtra("age");
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        textView2.setText(user_id);
        textView.setText(name);
        textView3.setText(gander);
        textView4.setText(user_age);
    }
}
```

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.wing.test2.test2/com.wing.test2.test2.patient};

Comment: u have to add the activity in manifest like: `<activity android:name=".patient" />`

Comment: inside your `application` tag

Comment: @YasirAmin if the answer helped...mark it as correct.

Comment: i appreciate your help dear .

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to declare it in Manifest. (according to error log in picture)
2. you define textView as EditText.

   textView3 = (EditText/*replace it with TextView*/) findViewById(R.id.textView3);